# MATLAB how to vectorize this while loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, while-loop, vectorization

so the idea here is to read data into a matrix, and then make that matrix a square matrix by removing the excess column(s) or row(s), but vectorized, without using any loops at all and without using if/else. is this possible?

this is the way i have it done with loop and if/else

```
load file.dat
r = num2str(size('file',1))
c = num2str(size('file',2))
while (r~=c) 
    if (r>c)
        r--
    else (c>r)
        c--
end
res = file(1:r,1:c)
save('squarefile.dat', 'res', '-ascii')
```

thank you

Comment: Sorry - but that must be one of the most inefficient algorithm to calculate a minimum.

Comment: @bdecaf - I'm working on another algorithm for computing minimum with O( 2^n ) ;-)

Comment: That is not valid matlab syntax. I guess you mean `r = r-1` and `c = c-1` instead of `r--` and `c--`

Comment: Also the use of num2str does not make sense so just skip that part.

Answer (score 4):

Given a matrix `A` that is nxm big, we'll create matrix `B` that is a square matrix, by removing excess columns or rows (depending which dimension is bigger) from `A`:

```
B=A(1:min(size(A)),1:min(size(A)));
```

by the way, this line can be also written as `A=A(1:min(size(A)),...)` if you want to overwrite `A` and delete the  excess info...